# FileUriExposedException when showing notification with sound

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-file

Users of my app can select the ringtone that should be played when they receive a notification within my app.

I show a ringtone selection dialog:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

and save the results:

```
    Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString(RINGTONE_SP_KEY, uri.toString()).apply();
```

When I show the notification, I use either the ringtone selected by the user or the default one:

```
private void showNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSound(getRingtone());
    builder.setContentText("MyContentText");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.test);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}

private Uri getRingtone() {

    String ringtoneUriFromSp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(RINGTONE_SP_KEY, null);

    if (ringtoneUriFromSp == null) {
        return RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    } else {
        return Uri.parse(ringtoneUriFromSp);
    }
}
```

Both the default as well as the custom selected ringtone `Uri` usually look something like this:

```
content://media/internal/audio/media/16
```

and everything works well.

**I do receive** though (quite rarely) **the following exception** via Crashlytics:

> Fatal Exception: android.os.FileUriExposedException
>   file:///storage/emulated/0/MIUI/ringtone/CloudMagic_3.ogg exposed
>   beyond app through Notification.sound

for some devices (e.g. Xiaomi Mi Max 2, Galaxy Tab A 10.1).

The [exception docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html) say this stems from the `Uri` being exposed via  `file:// Uri` (wrong way) instead of  `content:// Uri` (correct way) which I couldn't reproduce on any of my devices; both the default as well as the user selected ringtone `Uri` come via `content:// Uri`.

I don't know if this happens for the default ringtone obtained via

```
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```

or the ringtone selected by the user.

Has anyone experienced the same problem or knows what the problem could be here?

Comment: To debug this try : use API 26 emulator with SD card emulation, select ringtone from SD as default Ringtone(of course it may not show the error as the problem maybe in MIUI itself(fx it's still using file:// schema) ... To avoid either disable checks with `StrictMode`(not so good idea) or check if `RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri` return file schema and copy file(you may need to ask for a permissions) to app's local storage and use `FileProvider`(preferred way)

Comment: @Selvin: `FileProvider` does not work here, as we have no reliable means of granting read permission to the `Uri` content.

Comment: See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/07/notifications-sounds-android-7p0-aggravation.html) -- you may run into this problem on Android 7.0+ devices.

Comment: I get the same problem on some MIUI devices. The strange thing is that on my MIUI device I get a content URI from the external ringtone selection. But it seems on some other MIUI devices (also 7.1.1) they send back a file URI.

BUT on some MIUI devices the file URI does work on 7.1.1! Very confusing and I don't know how to solve.

@Ascorbin: How did you solve this problem?

Comment: @asco  any solution for this?

Comment: @SagarHudge No.

Comment: I have the same problem. I found an interesting thing. For example, the ZEDGE application can act as notification/ringtone picket and it returns URI in the form content://media/external/audio/media/# even on Xiaomi phone when default ringtone picker return file://storage/ for a custom sound. But I not found how to do that.